# PHP: Click on logo shall link to another page and display short "You are redirected to..." message

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, hyperlink

Disclaimer: I am no savant in this, otherwise I wouldn't ask you guys here. If you have a solution, please explain in a little more detail if necessary.

I use the blocksy theme. Upon clicking the logo, my homepage should link another website.
This can be achieved by adding this to the functions.php of the theme:

```
add_filter('blocksy:header:logo:url', function ($home_page) {
return 'https://mywebsite';
});
```

It works fine, but it would be good to display a short message "You are being redirected to www.website.com!"
Is there a simple way to display a template here that I created with Elementor? Just displaying a message would be fine, too.
It would also be great to open the link in a new tab, but PHP has no function for that, right?

Comment: Are we talking about wordpress here? If so please add the appropriate [tag:wordpress] tag, then your question is more likely to be seen by people with relevant expertise.

Comment: Yes, it's about wordpress.

Comment: Via JavaScript, you could prevent the link click default action, show a "you are being redirected" message, and then send the user to the actual target URL a bit later using `setTimeout`.

Comment: _"It would also be great to open the link in a new tab, but PHP has no function for that, right?"_ - no, because PHP does not know anything about any client-side "tabs" in the first place. This should rather be done in the template, where that link for your logo gets created, resp. using whatever filters it might provide to interject at this point. (You might be tempted to do that part in JavaScript as well - but if you include a delay to show your message, then this is likely to get caught in the popup blocker.)

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you! Assuming I can figure out the code, where do I implement it? Also in the functions.php?

Comment: That is generally a good place to add filter calls, yes. If you have no specific dependencies to any plugins, that works for most cases.